# Local function not updating referenced value in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Assuming the parent width is `200`.

When I run this initially, it prints:

```
current maxWidth: 200
```

I then increase the parent width to `600` and after recomposition it prints:

```
current maxWidth: 600
```

After I tap on the Box the local function `onTap` is called and it prints the old value:

```
onTap maxWidth: 200
```

What happens is that `onTap` captures the `constraints.maxWidth` value and it doesn't update it later. Any way to get the current value inside `onTap`?

```
  BoxWithConstraints(
    propagateMinConstraints = true,
    modifier = Modifier
      .background(Color.Green)
      .fillMaxSize()
  ) {
    println("current maxWidth: ${constraints.maxWidth}")

    fun onTap(position: Offset) {
      println("onTap maxWidth: ${constraints.maxWidth}")
    }

    Box(
      modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Blue)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
          detectTapGestures(onTap = ::onTap)
        }
    ) {

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pointerInput`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pointerInput(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) captures current scope. You can experience same behavior with some other Compose function, like `remember`, `LaunchedEffect`, etc: all of them have `vararg key` parameter.

To make it update the scope, you can pass any values on which your calculation depends to `key`, in your case:

```
.pointerInput(constraints.maxWidth) {
    detectTapGestures(onTap = ::onTap)
}
```